# How to send HTML selected date to PostgreSQL in a Query

Tags: php, html, postgresql, date

I need a little help with this, I've been trying to send the selected dates of my 2  in a Query to a PostgreSQL so I can set a range of dates (a Between) the thing is that I don't know if I'm doing it right, the user sets the date and a isset($_POST['date1]) is checked, then I do this

```
if (isset($_POST['date1'])) {
    $var_fecha2 = $_POST['date'];
        if ($var_fecha2 ==0) { //this since can be empty and for some reason if it is my var gets 0, but as you can see its covered
            $fecha2_bool = true;
        }else {
            $fecha2_bool = false;
            $opt = 1;
        }
}
```

After that I have conditionals but the main thing is this:

```
and sp.fec_grab between to_date('$var_fecha1','dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('$var_fecha2','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

The HTML date input sends the date as d-m-Y but as a String, I guess the to_date in the query sets the variable as a date, also I checked the column in PostgreSQL and its as 'd-m-Y' 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code. It might have errors as I haven't tested it, but the general idea is this:

```php
// cheackout "ternary operator", it's a shorter syntax for if/else
$from = isset($_POST['from']) ? date($_POST['from']) : false;
$to = isset($_POST['to']) ? date($_POST['to']) : false;

if (!$from) {
  // using die() as example, respond with better error to your request
  die("cannot query without a from date");
}

// validate from date
// - replace '/' with your expected input date separator in explode()
// - check the order of the elements in checkdate() to match your expected date inputs
$from = explode('/', $from);
if (count($from) != 3 || !checkdate($from[0], $from[1], $from[2]) {
  die("invalid from date");
}

// validate to date (only if present)
if ($to !== false) {
  $to = explode('/', $to);
  if (count($to) != 3 || !checkdate($to[0], $to[1], $to[2]) {
    die("invalid to date");
  }
}

// Ready to query
if (!$to) {
  // query: ...and sp.fec_grab > '$from'
} else {
  // query: ...and sp.fec_grab between '$from' and '$to'
}
```

Helpful links

- [Ternary Operator](https://www.codementor.io/@sayantinideb/ternary-operator-in-php-how-to-use-the-php-ternary-operator-x0ubd3po6)
- [checkdate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)